# GeoPoint - how to pass accuracy?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have such information for saving to ES in my json:

```
{
"geolocation": {
    "latitude": 50.443278299999996,
    "longitude": 30.5075698,
    "accuracy": 3966
  }
}
```

*geolocation*  in my Java object is GeoPoint (`private GeoPoint geolocation`). How I can pass an accuracy to GeoPoint? Or maybe there is another type for saving location with lat, lon and accuracy?

P.S. For parsing I use:

```
public GenericResponse<?> addUserInfo(@RequestBody UserInformation userInformation) {
 }
```

And *geolocation* is one of the fields in UserInformation class.

Comment: What do you mean by accuracy? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html . You can specify the distance if that's what you mean

Comment: Yes,  in my case this is distance. But how to put in Java GeoPoint? In this class I found only lat and lon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing something. Accuracy or distance, it's something that you specify when querying, not when saving something. For example:

- You have one entry in your elasticsearch. This entry has a geo_point field that includes lat and lon.
- When you search for this profile you have a geo point, which represents a location and you want, based on this location (let's name it query location) to find all entries in elasticsearch that have a distance of X meters from you.

Basically there is no distance/accuracy to save. Given a geo query, elasticsearch will calculate the distance between these two points and it will check if it is smaller than the distance/accuracy you provided (during query), if it is, it will include the entry.